# Can i use moment.js to convert millisec to hour over 24 hour

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert the millisec to hour over 24 hour
I using moment.js like

```
moment(1274468000).format('HH:mm')
```

I expect result is about 354 Hour
How can i do this.

Comment: timeInMs / 3600000 = hours

Comment: how about minutes
i want to display like XXX Hour : XXX Min

Comment: If you are trying to create a countdown, I would suggest you to use countdownjs. however you don’t need any additional library to create this. you can find example of vanilla JS here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Answer (score 0):

You don't need moment.JS to do so:

```
var time = (time) => (((time/3600000)|0) + ":" + ((time%3600000/60000)|0));
console.log(time(1274468000))
```

that would output:

```
354:1
```